# Mismatched input <eof> with drools

Tags: drools, eof, optaplanner

I have an Optaplanner drools file, and when I run the code below:

```
// ############################################################################
// Hard constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "DevCanOnlyDoOneTask"
when
    $T1:Task(assignedDev==$D)
    $T2:Task(assignedDev==$D)

    (($T2.getAllottedStartTime()<=$T1.getAllottedStartTime())&&($T1.getAllottedStartTime()<$T2.getAllottedStartTime()+$T2.getDuration()))||(($T1.getAllottedStartTime()<=$T2.getAllottedStartTime())&&($T2.getAllottedStartTime()<$T1.getAllottedStartTime()+$T1.getDuration())) //line 21

then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1000);
end

// ############################################################################
// Soft constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "MaximiseEarliestFinishTime"
when
    $TA: TaskAssignment($EFT: getEFT())        

then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,+$TA.getEFT());
```

I get the following error message (note I have commented on where the relevant are in the code above):

```
08:08:41.613 [main] ERROR o.d.c.k.b.impl.AbstractKieModule - Unable to build KieBaseModel:defaultKieBase
[21,36]: [ERR 102] Line 21:36 mismatched input '<=' in rule "DevCanOnlyDoOneTask"
[36,66]: [ERR 102] Line 36:66 mismatched input '<eof>' in rule "MaximiseEarliestFinishTime"
[0,0]: Parser returned a null Package
```

I assume there is something fundamentally wrong with the syntax I am using, but I am finding it difficult to pin down exactly what.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

```
Line 36:66 mismatched input '<eof>' in rule "MaximiseEarliestFinishTime"
```

All rules must end with the keyword `end`.

As for line 21, either put an `eval` around it (see drools docs for more info) or better yet, do those restrictions as part of `$T2:Task`. Also, the `$D` in `$T1:Task` doesn't exist yet, so you probably want to define it (bind it) instead of `==` compare it.